# Entity Framework Core to include different properties from subclasses

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

The structure of my classes and repository:

```
public class Group{
    //fields
}

public class User{
    public UserRole Role {get;set;}
}

public abstract class UserRole{
    //fields
}

public class PersonUserRole:UserRole{
    public Group Group {get;set;}
}

public class ManagerUserRole:UserRole{
    public IList<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}
```

An example where I encounter the issue:

```
public class UserRepository:IUserRepository{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<User> _users;

    public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbcontext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbcontext;
        _users = _dbContext.DomainUsers;
    }

    public User GetBy(int id)
        {
            User type = _users.Include(u => u.Role)
                              .SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserId == id);
            if (typeof(PersonUserRole) == type.Role.GetType())
            {
                return
                    _users.Include(u => u.Role)
                        .ThenInclude(r => (r as PersonUserRole).Groep)
                        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserId == id);
            }
            else
            {
                return _users.Include(u => u.Role)
                             .ThenInclude(r => (r as ManagerUserRole).Groups)
                             .SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserId == id);
            }
        }
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Message   "The property expression 'r => (r As PersonUserRole).Group' is not
>   valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't =>
>   t.MyProperty'

It seems like I cannot cast my `UserRole` Type to the actual `PersonUserRole` Type to include the Group/Groups property. How can I include the properties of the subclasses?

Comment: What if you try .ThenInclude(r => ((PersonUserRole)r).Group)  ?

Comment: @Mangist I'm afraid this returns a "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source" error. But I can't seem to find what the issue is.

Comment: It's null if your object can't be cast to a PersonUserRole. I'd personally just do this without LINQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Starting with version 2.1, [Include on derived types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#include-on-derived-types) is now naturally supported by EF Core via either cast or `as` operator inside lambda `Include` / `ThenInclude` overloads or `string` `Include` overload.

**Original answer (pre EF Core 2.1):**

Currently eager loading of derived entity navigation properties is not supported.

As a workaround you can use a combination of **Eager loading**, **Explicit loading** and **Querying related entities** explained in the [**Loading Related Data**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the EF Core documentation:

```
var user = _users.Include(u => u.Role).SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == id);
var userRoleQuery = db.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.Role).Query();
if (user.Role is ManagerUserRole)
    userRoleQuery.OfType<ManagerUserRole>().Include(r => r.Groups).Load();
else if (user.Role is PersonUserRole)
    userRoleQuery.OfType<PersonUserRole>().Include(r => r.Group).Load();
return user;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I'm trying it out, however, I can't seem to find the `Reference` method. Could you perhaps nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: [`Reference<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_1_Reference__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func__0___0___)

Comment: FYI link in the update has moved to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#include-on-derived-types . I would've edited but queue is full at time of comment

Comment: @Luke Shame on them, link breakers! Just kidding, thank you for pointing out, link updated.

Comment: A constant battle, isn't it? ;) Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 2):

EntityFramework has an open issue which is exacly the same as your problem: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3910

Maybe you can try what they suggest, but I can't try if it works:

> ```
> var o = context.Set<Order>()
>     .Where(o => o.Id == 1234)
>     .Single();
>
> context.Set<GroupPosition>()
>     .Where(x => x.Order == o)
>     .Include(x => x.GroupType)
>     .Load();
>
> context.Set<SalesPosition>()
>     .Where(x => x.Order == o)
>     .Include(x => x.Group)
>     .Load();
> ```

Comment: This solution is (highly) preferable to accepted one when multiple entities are requested.