# Including derived child properties in Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core 2.0, I am trying to construct a query to include related data for a polymorphic child entity.

For example, given the following types:

```
    public class ParentEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IList<ChildEntityBase> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class ChildEntityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildEntityA : ChildEntityBase
    {
    }

    public class ChildEntityB : ChildEntityBase
    {
        public IList<GrandchildEntity> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class GrandchildEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }
```

and the following configuration:

```
    public DbSet<ParentEntity> ParentEntities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<ParentEntity>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.Entity<ParentEntity>().HasMany(p => p.Children).WithOne();

        builder.Entity<ChildEntityBase>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Entity<ChildEntityBase>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("ChildEntityType")
            .HasValue<ChildEntityA>("a")
            .HasValue<ChildEntityB>("b");

        builder.Entity<ChildEntityA>()
            .HasBaseType<ChildEntityBase>();

        builder.Entity<ChildEntityB>()
            .HasBaseType<ChildEntityBase>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Children).WithOne();

        builder.Entity<GrandchildEntity>()
            .HasBaseType<ChildEntityBase>();

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

I am trying to write the following query:

```
        var result = this.serviceDbContext.ParentEntities
            .Include(p => p.Children)
            .ThenInclude((ChildEntityB b) => b.Children);
```

Unfortunately, this is resulting in a syntax error.

However, I believe I am following the syntax as specified in https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/commit/07afd7aa330da5b6d90d518da7375d8bbf676dfd

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality is not available in EFC 2.0.

It's been tracked as [#3910 Query: Support Include/ThenInclude for navigation on derived type](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3910) and according to the current EFC [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap), it's scheduled for EFC 2.1 release (**Include for derived types** item under 
[Features we have committed to complete](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap#features-we-have-committed-to-complete)).

Comment: That would explain it.  Is there an alternative approach I can use to ThenInclude appropriately for polymorphic child types?

Comment: No, that's the problem :( Until they provide it, you have to do it manually (basically using explicit loading) - like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704826/entity-framework-core-to-include-different-properties-from-subclasses/42705673#42705673). But there is no workaround w/o materializing the query.

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  Been very helpful.